# How do I display only some objects in django?

Tags: python, html, django

I have a basic blog app, where you can write blogs from the django admin panel. I want to display only ten blogs per page(on the public homepage) and then display the next ten blogs in the next page and so on and display a page number at the bottom of the page, like stackoverflow does on the questions page. It displays 15 questions and then shows which page you're currently on. I am new to django and don't know if any function is available for this purpose. I tried searching on google and stackoverflow, but cannot find any relevant answer.

Comment: Yes, you can *paginate a `ListView`*: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/pagination/#paginating-a-listview

Comment: Thanks @WillemVanOnsem